# Azure Boards - WSJF Score field not calculating

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile, azure-boards

My team recently migrated over to the updated ADO site. When we create a feature on our board, we still have a planning section where we can input values into Effort, Business Value, Time Criticality, and RROE. On the old version of the site, our WSJF score would be automatically calculated and updated once all these values are in. Now, our WSJF score never calculates so we have to manually calculate and input the values.

Is this feature not available anymore, or can we do something to fix this?

I can click an action called "Re-calculate WSJF Values", but nothing happens. Any ideas on how to approach this would be great!

Comment: Whatever you're talking about here is not a built-in feature of Azure Boards. It sounds like you're using an extension. I don't know what you mean by "migrated over to the updated ADO site" -- do you mean that you migrated from on-prem Azure DevOps Server to Azure DevOps cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone over any work item customization and workflow changes you had made on the previous version. Additionally, you may also need to add back in the marketplace extensions you used to use, on your new ADO site. RROE is a custom field, with some custom logic behind it. It needs wiring back up.